# how to make apache ignite scale linearly with increase in Number of nodes?

Tags: performance, query-optimization, cluster-computing, ignite

I'm running some tests and found that 1 node is faster and produces more result than 2 and 4 nodes? I'm not able to understand why it is happening.

I'm using `parition_aware=True` and `lazy=True` while writing and querying data to ignite.

here are some of the result I got. Its for crossJoin of two 100k row tables.

[Results I got after running some queries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eI6kg.png)

Answer (score 2):

Different result sets for different Ignite topologies is an implicit indicator that your [affinity](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/data-modeling/affinity-collocation#affinity-colocation) collocation configuration is incorrect. You need to distribute your entries across a cluster in the particular way allowing to join tables locally. Make sure that `leads` and `products` have the same affinity key column, and use it for your join. This concept is called [collocated join](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/SQL/distributed-joins#collocation-joins), it helps to avoid additional network hops.

For this particular case it seems you are trying to calculate Levenshtein distance, the only way to do that is cross join, it's basically a ***cartesian product*** of tables. It means that for each row from the left table you'll need to traverse all the records from the right table (there are some possible optimisations though). The only way to achieve that is to leverage [non-collocated](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/SQL/distributed-joins#non-collocated-joins) joins. But keep in mind that it implies additional network activity. Here's a rough estimation of how much we actually need.

Assume we want to compute the cross join of tables `A` and `B`. Let's also assume that the table `A` contains `n` rows and the table `B` contains `m` rows. In that case for a cluster with `k` nodes (we are not taking backups into account, they don't take part in SQL) we would come up with some complexity estimation in terms of network data transfer.

There are [image: 5] rows in the table `A` on every node on the average. For every node-local row in `A` there are approximately [image: 4] rows in `B` (residing on the other nodes) to fetch through network. Having `k` nodes total we'll have the required network activity proportional to [image: 6]. With the growing number of nodes it will creep up to [image: 6] (the entire dataset squared). And it's not really good in fact. Having a smaller number of nodes actually decreases the network load in this scenario.

In a nutshell:

- try enabling distributed joins, it will fix the result set size
- it's difficult to say what's going on without profiling and query execution plans